# Difference between two lists of lists in Python

Tags: python, set, difference

I have two lists of lists:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [[1,2,3],[9,9,9]]
```

I would like to get a set difference between them - expected outcome:

```
c = a - b = [[4,5,6],[7,8,9]].
```

I tried set() and set.difference() but it seems not to be able to compare lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use list comprehensions like so:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [[1,2,3],[9,9,9]]
c = [d for d in a if d not in b]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through one and check if it's in the other.

`[numbers for numbers in a if numbers not in b]`